# How to change FutureBuilder connection.state in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

Here i am hitting an api to get the data but and i am getting the data as i have printed the data. But when i am using FutureBuilder connection.state it is returning none and returns the view. I want to know how to change the state of connection.state to Done so that i can show my view.

```
*class DashboardScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashboardScreen createState() => _DashboardScreen();
}
class _DashboardScreen extends State<DashboardScreen> {
Future<DashboardModel> futureDashboard;
//   api hit

@override
      void didChangeDependencies() {
        super.didChangeDependencies();
        Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async{
            
            futureDashboard = dashboardData();
          }
          );
        });
      }
```

// here is dashboard data

```
Future<dynamic> dashboardData() async {
    pr.show();
    final String url =
        '${GlobalConfiguration().getString('api_base_url')}${GlobalConfiguration().getString('dashboard')}';

    final response = await http.post(
      url,
      body: {
        "auth_key": '${GlobalConfiguration().getString('auth_key')}',
      },
    );

    responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(response.body);
    DashboardModel dashboardModel = DashboardModel.fromJson(map);
    _dashboard = DashboardModel.fromJson(responseJson);
    if (_dashboard.statusCode == "200") {

      final String responseString = response.body;


      pr.hide();
      showSimpleFlushbar(context, 'Successful');
      return dashboardModelFromJson(responseString);
    } else {

      pr.hide();
      return null;
    }
  }



// setting the data in the view created
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

// scaffold view
    return new Scaffold(
      
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
    
padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
    child: FutureBuilder<DashboardModel>(
        future: futureDashboard,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DashboardModel> futureDashboard) {
          switch (futureDashboard.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
              return Container(
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                          'No Connection Message')
                  )
              );
            case ConnectionState.active:
              return Text('Active result...');
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Text('Awaiting result...');
            case ConnectionState.done:
              print(futureDashboard);
              if (futureDashboard.hasData) {
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text("data"),);
                    } else if (futureDashboard.hasError) {
                  return showSimpleFlushbar(context, "${futureDashboard.error}");
                }
                return Container(
                  child: Text('error'),
                );
              }
              return Container(
                child: Text('errornot'),
              );
          }),
  ),
);
}*
```

Comment: Would you post your dashboardData() code?

Comment: I guess there is no error on the log! Right?

Comment: You don't need to change the future builder state. Simple use ``FutureBuilder()`` and check if status == done and then show. You can find more information here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: @LapaNyAinaTanjona no i am not

Comment: @OMiShah let me try thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when there is an uncaught exception in the Future. Have you debugged your code? Try to put a debug break point right after `response` assignment and see if you actually are getting a response. This will help you to understand whether your code works at all.

PS. Side note: do not `pr.show() / hide();` or  `showSimpleFlushbar(context, 'Successful');` in the function. These belong to the `builder` part of the FutureBuilder because these have to deal with redrawing the widget tree. Best case it that those code lines won't work, worst case that they give you weird errors.

Comment: I/FA      ( 8558): Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
I/flutter ( 8558): null
I/flutter ( 8558): ConnectionState.none
I/flutter ( 8558): false
I/flutter ( 8558): 200
I/flutter ( 8558): Success
I/flutter ( 8558): 3
I/flutter ( 8558): passed


this is what i am getting in console

Comment: Learn about debugging here if you are not familiar with the topic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RcY4lX3SeEo

Comment: sir i have debugged the app i am not getting any error and i can see success message from the api.

But first ConnectionState.none gets executed after that i can see response of my api though after that ConnectionState don't redirect to active or any other state.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the code

```
Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async{
            
            futureDashboard = dashboardData();
          }
          );
        });
```

to `initState` without the `Future.delayed`

Comment: okay just use `dashboardData()` directly with `FutureBuilder`